# How do you read a textfile using a scanner into a Swing control component?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In an array class I have the following code and would like to use the name, surname and score variables to be loaded into a jList. How would I do so?

```
private static User uArr [] = new User [10];
private static int size = 0;
public UserArray () throws FileNotFoundException {

try
{
    Scanner fcFile = new Scanner (new File ("user.txt"));
    String line, name, surname;
    int score;

    while (fcFile.hasNext())
    {
        line = fcFile.nextLine();
        Scanner cfFile = new Scanner (line); 
        name = cfFile.next(); 
        surname = cfFile.next();
        score = cfFile.nextInt(); 
        cfFile.close();
        uArr[size] = new User (name,surname,score);
        size++;
    }

    fcFile.close();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException f)
{
    System.out.println("File Not Found - Check File Name And Path Again.");
}
```

Comment: testField.setText();  did you try it >

Comment: Please read the complete article [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). This will help you to understand, how to work with `JList`.

Comment: Instead of the array `User uArr [] = new User [10];` the code might hold a reference to a [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) & add each newly created `User` to that model. The list model can then be used to create the `JList`, or set as the model. This is covered in [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Please go through the tutorial before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

> would like to use the name, surname and score variables to be loaded into a jList

A JList is used to store a single piece of data. Since you want to display an object containing 3 pieces of data then you should use a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples to get you started.

When using a `JTable` you could use the `DefaultTableModel` and store each piece of data separately into the `TablemModel` without using your `User` class.

Or, if you want to add the `User` class to the `JTable` then you will need to create a custom TableModel. Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example of creating a custom model for an object.